# knockout.js Components content

Tags: javascript, html, web, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a custom Component with Knockout.js, I already have this code pices:

The .js file of the control:

```
ko.components.register("expand-button",{
    viewModel: function(data)
    {
        this.header = data.header;

        this.image= data.image;

        this.displayContent = ko.observable(false);

        this.toogle = function()
        {
            if(this.displayContent()==true)
            {
                this.displayContent(false);
            }
            else
            {
                this.displayContent(true);
            }
        }
    },
    template: { require: 'text!controls/expand-button/expand-button.html'}
});
ko.applyBindings();
```

The template of the control:

```
<div class="ExpandButtonContainer">
    <div data-bind="click: toogle" class="ExpandButtonButtonInactive">
            <div class="ExpandButtonImage"><image data-bind="visible: image" src=""  /></div>
        <div data-bind="text: header">Header</div>
    </div>  
    <div class="ExpandButtonContent" data-bind="visible: displayContent() == true" data-part="content"></div>
</div>
```

Now I want to add a Html Content to Control so if I use the Control like this:

```
<expand-button params="header: 'HEADER'">The Content goes here as Html code</expand-button>
```

The text "The Content goes here as Html code" should be displayed in the div with the style class "ExpandButtonContent".
Has somebody an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the html binding? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/html-binding.html
For example:

```
<expand-button params="header: 'HEADER'"><span data-bind="html: yourhtmlcontent"></span></expand-button>
```

Or if you want to display the "text" itself,

```
    <expand-button params="header: 'HEADER'"><pre data-bind="text: yourhtmlcontent"></pre></expand-button>
```

Comment: The problem is, how to define at which position in the control-template the html should be displayed.